# Can I use "techs" in a domain name instead of "tech"?

Tags: programming, abbreviations

Is it normal to use `*techs.info` instead of `*tech.info` in a domain name? Is this correct, or can I not reduce "technology" to "techs"?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking if the short-form of technology is _tech_ or _techs_?

Comment: Yes. Cause the domain with **tech.info already in used and i think to use techs.info (it's very hard to find good name for your site).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Technology* in its singular form cannot be abbreviated to *techs*. But if there are clearly more than one technology in use, *techs* would certainly be OK. Yet most would use or understand *techs* as an abbreviation of *technicians*.

An alternative would be to abbreviate *technology* with *tex*.

Comment: +1, might it be the origin of [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Eldros: according to Wikipedia, "the name of TeX derives from the Greek: τέχνη (skill, art, technique); for this reason, TeX's creator Donald Knuth promotes a pronunciation of /ˈtɛx/ (tekh) (that is, with a voiceless velar fricative as in Modern Greek, similar to the last sound of the German word 'Bach', the Spanish 'j' sound, or as *ch* in *loch*)."